# standardize text using phonetic

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i received data from a datacenter and i have to cleanse and make data useful and my biggest problem is one column lets call it "service_description" and for example the data center belong to a hair salon, this column is filled manually (text box) and contain huge amount of data (Billions), here is a small sample

```
service description

washed the haair 
hair washed and dried
used shampoo on har
nails manicure
nail paint
nail pant
paint the nails
```

what i need to do is get each category together by ruining a script that will analyze each line and give it  specif category e.g. hair could be the category for the first three lines because it is repeated in all of them while nail is category for the rest, taking in consideration the category word could be misspelled.

results

```
service description          possible categories

washed the haair                       hair
hair washed and dried                  hair
used shampoo on har                    hair
nails manicure                         nail
nail paint                             nail
nail pant                              nail
paint the nails                        nail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your categories are fixed lookup.
I would split the string by white spaces; and for each part I would go through all items in your categories lookup, and pick the one with minimum levenshtein distance.

Some references:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm